# XAML Application throwing .Net System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xaml, desktop-application

Copied the exe and the required dll's from the Release folder to the remote location. and it shows this error and does not start up an application.

App config code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ytf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Here is the XAML code..

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public static string SourceApp = "iaPrefDBConn";
            IALogging iaLogging = new IALogging(SourceApp);
            IRegistry registryWrap = new RegistryWrap();
            IRegistryManager registryManager = null;
            IEnvironment environmentWrap = new EnvironmentWrap();
            IWTSDBConnectionManager wtsdbConnectionManager = null;
            ICommandLineManager cmdLinemanger = null;
            InstantAccess.Core iaCore = new InstantAccess.Core();

            public MainWindow()
            {
                try
                {
                    registryManager = new RegistryManager(registryWrap);
                    cmdLinemanger = new CommandLineManager(registryManager, environmentWrap);
                    wtsdbConnectionManager = new WTSDBConnectionManager(cmdLinemanger);
                    InitializeComponent();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    iaLogging.log(IALogging.LOG_ERROR, "Exception in starting application: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Here is the application error status.

```
Application: iaPrefDBConn_WPF.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
  at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, 
  System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, 
  System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
  at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, 
  Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, 
  System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, 
   System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at
```

Comment: What is "ytf", shouldn't that be "utf"?

Comment: Yeah. Spell mistake. Sorry. Its utf-8

Comment: can you post your XAML here?

Comment: Have added the constructor code.. Please look into it